# count of entries in data frame in R

Tags: r, count, dataframe

I'm looking to get a count for the following data frame:

```
> Santa
   Believe Age Gender Presents Behaviour
1    FALSE   9   male       25   naughty
2     TRUE   5   male       20      nice
3     TRUE   4 female       30      nice
4     TRUE   4   male       34   naughty
```

of the number of children who believe. What command would I use to get this?

(The actual data frame is much bigger. I've just given you the first four rows...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use `table`:

```
R> x <- read.table(textConnection('
   Believe Age Gender Presents Behaviour
1    FALSE   9   male       25   naughty
2     TRUE   5   male       20      nice
3     TRUE   4 female       30      nice
4     TRUE   4   male       34   naughty'
), header=TRUE)

R> table(x$Believe)

FALSE  TRUE 
    1     3
```

Answer (score 24):

I think of this as a two-step process:

1. subset the original data frame according to the filter supplied
   (Believe==FALSE); then
2. get the row count of this subset

For the first step, the ***subset*** function is a good way to do this (just an alternative to ordinary index or *bracket* notation).

For the second step, i would use ***dim*** or ***nrow***

One advantage of using *subset*: you don't have to parse the result it returns to get the result you need--just call *nrow* on it directly.

so in your case:

```
v = nrow(subset(Santa, Believe==FALSE))     # 'subset' returns a data.frame
```

or wrapped in an *anonymous function*:

```
>> fnx = function(fac, lev){nrow(subset(Santa, fac==lev))}

>> fnx(Believe, TRUE)
      3
```

Aside from *nrow*, *dim* will also do the job. This function returns the *dimensions* of a data frame (rows, cols) so you just need to supply the appropriate index to access the number of rows:

```
v = dim(subset(Santa, Believe==FALSE))[1]
```

An answer to the OP posted before this one shows the use of a contingency table. I don't like that approach for the general problem as recited in the OP. Here's the reason. Granted, the general problem of *how many rows in this data frame have value x in column C?* can be answered using a contingency table as well as using a "filtering" scheme (as in my answer here). If you want row counts for all values for a given factor variable (column) then a contingency table (via calling *table* and passing in the column(s) of interest) is the most sensible solution; however, the OP asks for the count of a *particular* value in a factor variable, not counts across all values. Aside from the performance hit (might be big, might be trivial, just depends on the size of the data frame and the processing pipeline context in which this function resides). And of course once the result from the call to table is returned, you still have to *parse* from that result just the count that you want.

So that's why, to me, this is a filtering rather than a cross-tab problem.

Comment: In fact `nrow` is just a wrapper for `dim`

Answer (score 15):

```
sum(Santa$Believe)
```

Comment: I think this is probably the fastest way.

Comment: This is the fastest solution for this particular case, no doubt about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `summary(santa$Believe)` and you will get the count for `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

DPLYR makes this really easy.

```
x<-santa%>%
   count(Believe)
```

If you wanted to count by a group; for instance, how many males v females believe, just add a `group_by`:

```
x<-santa%>%
   group_by(Gender)%>%
   count(Believe)
```

Answer (score 0):

A *one-line* solution with `data.table` could be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[,.N,by=Believe]
   Believe N
1:   FALSE 1
2:    TRUE 3
```

Answer (score 0):

using `sqldf` fits here:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT Believe, Count(1) as N FROM Santa
       GROUP BY Believe")
```